# Kohana method to remove image files from server uploaded by FCKEditor

Tags: php, file, kohana, delete-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [kohana3.0 how to completely delete image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938742/kohana3-0-how-to-completely-delete-image-file)

What method or function in Kohana 3 do I use to remove an image file from the server that was uploaded/inserted by an HTML editor such as FCKEditor?

Or is there a specific PHP class that will work for this?

Answer (score 3):

nope, it is php function for this - [unlink](http://php.net/unlink)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Jocelyn: it contains the function name. Having it any person may read the official documentation

Comment: I disagree. If that were sufficient we would post link-only answers to all Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @Jocelyn: you're free to flag my answer, downvote it or add your own. Personally I don't see anything wrong in answering to RTFM-like question by RTFM links

Comment: Anyway, the question is a duplicate, it should have been closed long ago.

Comment: @Jocelyn: find one and vote for closing ;-)

Comment: Found duplicate and voted for closing :)

Comment: @zerkms: As good as not answering at all... saves you some effort ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: well, let me decide myself when to answer and how to answer. And thanks for downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Somebody else did. I just came along and closed the question after they flagged.

Comment: @BoltClock: but anyway, it's just stupid. The question has the only valid answer - RTFM and the link to FM. Not sure if citing manuals in these cases is what SO supposed to be for.