# kohana3.0 how to completely delete image file?

Tags: php, image, kohana, kohana-3, delete-file

I have a kohana3.0 content and files management system, and I would like to be able to completely delete images from database, and from my folder where I have uploaded them, when a user deletes an image. Now I use for image deletion:

```
 public function delete($id = NULL)
{
    parent::delete($id);
    unlink($this->path);
}
```

this in the image model. But it doesn't actually delete my image at all.

How can an image file be deleted in kohana 3.0?

Comment: are you sure $this->path is a valid location for the image? Try putting `die($this->path);` in front of it and get to know it the location is correct. Perhaps you first need to do a `parent::get($id)` in order to have the data ready in $this->path. (I'm not known with kohana btw, just some tips that might work)

Comment: I'm not sure, just to be sure for yourself check the model for the images, there perhaps is a get/select/fetch method based on an ID which you can use to get the filepath if it is not set already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea about kohana, but the unlink() function is how files are deleted in PHP.  If this isn't working, it is possible you just have a permissions problem with those files.